# SSRS REPORT for summary and individual

Tags: reporting-services, report

I wanted to generate a ssrs report with summary totals of all the total users on the page 1
and 
second page,third page.... onwards it should display all the individual  user.

Comment: Have you considered using sub reports?  Have a main report and inside each group place a sub report that does all the details you want

Comment: I am not sure that I understood your question, but you can use group, totals and page brake to achieve "display all the individual use". https://youtu.be/keBOCdMfelU

Comment: I used sub reports and was able to resolve it.